# drawing sequence diagram in real time

Tags: linux, diagram

I am looking for a tool/framework/library which will allow me to create a sequence diagram between interacting components i.e. client and server in real time or say almost real time. The server logs whatever it has received and sent with a label 'sent' and 'received'.

Constraint: I cannot change the server code and only allowed to read/monitor the server log.

Comment: How do you want to view the sequence diagram? In the browser? In the app? Would a text file (ASCII art) be ok, if you could `tail` it to constantly see the newest messages?  If the app were Windows only, but could run in Linux under Wine, would that be ok? And, can you code?

Comment: The server is running on linux, at present I just do tail -f of the log file and see the messages but I wanted to create an animation/pictorial representation of latest 5 send/receive between client server. My wish is to create a web app i.e. see in browser so that it can be visible from anywhere. I already found bokeh [python framweork] to do create a webapp but I could not create a sequence diagram.

Comment: Are you looking for a visual diagram to present? Or do you need raw data?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it yourself by periodically reading the last few entries of the log file in Python and generating "Ascii art" E.g. `Sender ------ (message name) ----> receiver`.

Or, you could read the last few lines of the log file and generate an input file for [msgcgen](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/), or [MSG Generator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msc-generator/) (which I consider to be far superior. Plus Zoltan gives good & quick email help & welcomes new features).

Since you mention a web app, you could search for some JS which will generate an MSC from a textual description. Maybe something like [this](https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/)?

Check the demo on the site & fork it on GitHub.

Comment: How to keep updating it ?

Comment: How do you want to present it? If you bury it in HTML, you can use a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="X">` tag to auto-refresh the page every X seconds and just generate the MSC as an image which you embed in the page.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No, I still didn't find the ready to use solution

Comment: If you know JS, I would recommend https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/ from my answer. It should be trivial to do.  Good luck

Comment: It doesn't generate graph in real time.

Comment: No, it doesn't your code does. Something as simple as a [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag in the HTML header would do it `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">`, or you could have a 1 second (or whatever) timer your JS, delete the diagram from the DOM and recreate it. If you want to get fancy, calculate the MD5 of the log file each time and only do something if it changed. Are we getting close to a solution here?

Comment: I tried that, the logs are getting written to syslog and reading and feeding to it, doesn't update it with refresh.

Comment: If the log file is grown and your code is not reading that, it sounds like a coding error.  Maybe post it to so? If so, please leave a link here & I will take a look at it.  Just to be clear - are you saying that it does draw the MSC one time, but does no update it, with a meta refresh in the HTML header, even though the log file is growing?

Comment: Did you eve get a solution for this? If you can specify more, maybe add a sample log file, I could take it on as a hobby project. Especially if you use a standard, well know, log file format